# Exclude sub directories recursively from folder

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, rsync

I have some sub-folders in this path `app/static/uploads/`

I am expecting that `--exclude="uploads"` will do the job of ignoring everything in sub-folders. However I am still getting things like `app/static/uploads/companies/headers/photo.jpg` synced. Any idea how to ignore the sync of everything in the `uploads` folder?

```
switches: -vzr  --exclude="uploads" --exclude=".git" --exclude=".github" --exclude=".gitattributes" --exclude=".gitignore"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exclude pattern is not **regex** compliant for your intent.

You would need to do something like the following:

```
EXCL_DIRS="--exclude='*/uploads/*'"
EXCL_SUFS="--exclude='.git' --exclude='.github' --exclude='.gitattributes' --exclude='.gitignore'"

rsync --recursive --compress --verbose ${EXCL_DIRS} ${EXCL_SUFS}
```

If all the EXCL_SUFS specifications are to address files under your EXCL_DIRS, then you don't need to define EXCL_SUFS.

**It is advisable** to use the **--dry-run** option until you are sure that your command structure will perform as desired (as visually verified by examining the file list reported by rsync).